# how to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\cdot 4x^{2}e^{-2x^2} e^{-a(b-x)^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been struggling to evaluate the integral.:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\cdot 4x^{2}e^{-2x^2} e^{-a(b-x)^2} $$

This is what I did so far.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\cdot 4x^{2}e^{-2x^2} e^{-a(b-x)^2} = \int dx\cdot 4x^{2}e^{-[(2+a)x^2+ab^2-2abx]}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I was thinking of applying the formula
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{(ax^2+bx+c)}dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}}$$
as the next step

Comment: Consider $\displaystyle f(a)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{(ax^2+bx+c)}~dx. $ What's $\frac{1}{2}f'(a)$?

Comment: The equation in the title does not match the text.

Comment: \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{(ax^2+bx+c)}dx & = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}} \\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{(ax^2+bx+c)}dx & = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a\sqrt{a}}e^{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}}+ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\frac{-4c-4}{16a^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: @user126924 You're done then I assume? Just match the coefficients if not.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx\cdot4x^2e^{-2x^2} = 0$

Because integrand is an odd function.

You can use the method of separation of variables

Comment: What exactly do you mean by separation of variables?